# Xamarin autocompleteview usage

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Which widget should I use such that the user can see the names in the dropdown from sqlite database if he types his name or email or phone number, Somewhat like facebook's search.
If the user types his name, the dropdown must show all the same names. Since there can be more than one person with the same name, he can then choose the one which is his.
If the user types his email or phone number, the dropdown must show the NAME after matching it from the database.

Any suggestions on how to do this ?
Which widget should I use for this, SearchView or AutoCompleteView or some other widget.
How can I then get the string of that selected value from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this link (AutoComplete Tutorial) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/autocompletetextview-in-xamarin/